# Sentiment Analysis from Twitter using R

Tags: r

I am getting below error while executing my code.

> Error while entering PIN
>
> Error Message :
> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :
> Could not resolve host:

```
download.file(url = 'http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem', destfile = 'cacert-pem')
    oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth",
                   access = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token")
    reqURL <- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
    accessURL <- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
     authURL <- 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'
    consumerKey <- "xxxxx"
    consumerSecret = "xxxx"
    accesstoken = "xxxx"
    accesssecret = "xxxxxv"
    Cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             authURL=authURL)
    
    Cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file('CurlSSL','cacert.pem', package = 'RCurl'))
```

Comment: **For all those who have down voted this question. You must tell the reason for the same. This is valid question. **

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to (httr) package, same happening with me waiting for result.